# Unit tests involving MockWebServer fails with Auth0's Android library version 2

Tags: android, auth0, junit5, mockk, rx-java3

We upgraded our Auth0 Android library from 1.30 to 2.0 and some of our unit tests that use OkHttp's `MockWebServer` broke.

1. The first test fails with a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` which in turn is caused by `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked.`
2. Next three tests fail with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.auth0.android.request.internal.DefaultThreadSwitcher`
3. The rest of the tests are stuck until cancelled.

For context, we use RxJava3 and Android Jetpack libs such as LiveData in our code base, and Retrofit for REST API.

I tried adding
`@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class, RxImmediateScheduler::class)` in the class declaration like this:

```
@ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class, RxImmediateScheduler::class)
class AuthManagerTest {
```

But afterwards, all tests return with "Test ignored" in the logs:

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.registerExtension(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:176)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.createRegistryFrom(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ExtensionUtils.populateNewExtensionRegistryFromExtendWithAnnotation(ExtensionUtils.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Here is a code snippet on how we initialize the test class:

```
class AuthManagerTest {

    ...
    private lateinit var authManager: AuthManager
    private lateinit var config: Auth0Config
    private lateinit var server: MockWebServer

    @MockK
    private lateinit var context: Context

    @MockK
    private lateinit var credentialsManager: SecureCredentialsManager

    ...

    ...

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        every { context.getSharedPreferences(any(), any()) } returns mockk()
        every { credentialsManager.authToken } returns null
        every { credentialsManager.userId } returns null
        every { credentialsManager.refreshToken } returns null
        every { credentialsManager.saveCredentials(any()) } just Runs

        ...

        mockkObject(Credentials.Companion)
        every { Credentials.fromAuth0Creds(any(), any()) } returns mockk()
        server = MockWebServer().apply {
            // we didn't use useHttps before but with the new version of Auth0 it seems https is mandatory
            useHttps(testSslSocketFactory(), false)
            start()
        }
...
}
```

Here is the first test that fails:

```
    @Test
    fun `sendEmailCode returns EmailSent when response is successful`() {
        server.enqueue(mockResponse(200, email_success_response))
        val emailResult = authManager.sendEmailCode("me@example.org").blockingGet()
                as EmailResult.EmailSent
        assertEquals("me@example.org", emailResult.email)
        assertNoToken()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed with version 2.3.0 of Auth0 android lib--see the README on how to solve this issue [here](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Android#unit-testing-with-junit-4-or-junit-5)